# Cocoa applications from the command line

Tags: cocoa, bundle, xib, nib

I've been attempting to create a Cocoa (desktop) application without using NIBs or XIBs, following the instructions [here](http://casperbhansen.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/dev-tip-nibless-development/). All is well, and from Terminal.app I can successfully run the application. However it's spawned without any of the usual decorations, such as a menu bar or a dock icon, *behind* the terminal window and seemingly attached very much to the terminal process.

I suspected that this might be a consequence of running the binary itself directly from the command line, but playing around a bit I found that at least `Calculator.app` is more than happy to spawn a "real" application when called using:

```
$ /Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator
```

What am I missing, if anything, here? I have also tried loading a XIB file via

```
NSNib *mainNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL URLWithString:@"../MainMenu.xib"] absoluteURL]];
[NSNib instantiateNibWithOwner:application topLevelObjects:nil];
```

which seems to find the XIB, but makes no difference (i.e. the GUI isn't fully loaded).

Comment: Are you running your program from within a bundle?

Comment: Not at the moment--I'm trying to avoid it if I can. I don't mind having a separate NIB, but ideally I'd like to avoid the whole .app structure if possible. My quick experiment with Calculator.app suggests what I'm after could be possible, unless it's loading in it's own bundle via some magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling, I found the solution to the issue. Transforming the process type via `TransformProcessType` and then using the accurately-named `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]` did the trick:

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess }; 
OSStatus returnCode = TransformProcessType(& psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);

[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

(I also added a custom menu to finish it off). Thanks to Mankarse for the pointers!

Answer (score 1):

You need a NSApplication.. why are you even doing this?

If you create a new GUI application, look at main.m you see that it is spawninng a NSApplication there.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
}
```

This requires you to have a bundle btw and if you want to launch a command line utility without the terminal you could either use launchd or create a bundle that you simply double click in the finder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have an NSApplication object (code not posted for clarity, but it's basically the same as on the link I mentioned). As for why I'm doing it, it's because the code that I need to run is cross-platform; I'm interested in creating a window that the cross-platform section can draw into, and I'd like to know whether that's possible without all of the usual app scaffolding.

Comment: @r_. It is certainly possible (but it relies on undocumented interfaces). Have a look at how libraries such as [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org) do it. Also have a look at [this](http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/05/16/working-without-a-nib-part-1/). The `osx_tell_dock` hack might also interest you (see [here](http://svn.tomasu.org/index.cgi/allegro/view/allegro/tags/4.4.2/src/macosx/system.m)).